# Problem: when the sum of two squares is a square

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

Please, I need help to solve the following problem:

> Let $K$ be a field with characteristic different from $2$ and $3$. Show that the following statement are equivalent:
>
> 1. The sum of two squares of $K$ is a square in $K$
> 2. If a cubic polynomial splits on $K$ then also its derivative splits on $K$

I wrote something in the case $1\Rightarrow2$:
we  can suppose that the cubic $f$ is monic and that $f=(X-a_1)(X-a_2)(X-a_3)$. After a calculation we have
$$f'=3X^2-2(a_1+a_2+a_3)X+a_1a_2+a_2a_3+a_1a_3$$
and it is enough to prove that the discriminant of $f'$ is a square. So calculating the discriminant:

$$\Delta=4(a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2-a_1a_2-a_2a_3-a_1a_3)$$

But then I can't continue, I should express $\Delta$ as sum of squares. Any idea about $2\Rightarrow 1$?

Thanks in advance

Comment: $\Delta = 2\bigl((a_1 - a_2)^2  + (a_2 - a_3)^2 + (a_3 - a_1)^2\bigr)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To summarize :

$(1) \Rightarrow (2)$ If (1) is true, then by induction any sum of squares
is itself a square. Daniel Fischer’s formula $\Delta=
2(\sum_{i \lt j}(a_i-a_j)^2)$ shows that $\Delta$ is a sum of six squares,
so $\Delta$ is itself a square.

$(2) \Rightarrow (1)$ Suppose that (2) is true. Let $a,b\in K$. We must
show that $a^2+b^2$ is a square. We may assume WLOG that $a$ and $b$ are 
nonzero.
The cubic polynomial $Q_1=(X-\frac{1}{2})(X-\frac{2}{2})(X-\frac{3}{2})$ splits
over $K$, so its derivative $Q’_1=3X^2-6X+\frac{11}{4}$ also splits
over $K$, so $3={\sf disc}(Q'_1)$ is a square in $K$.

The cubic polynomial $Q_2=\frac{(X^2-3)(aX-b)}{6}$ splits
over $K$, so its derivative $Q’_2=\frac{a}{2}X^2-bX-\frac{a}{2}$ 
also splits over $K$, so $a^2+b^2={\sf disc}(Q'_1)$ is a square in $K$
as wished.